# Writing a specific nth-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need some help with writing a nth-child selector in CSS for the following situations

Children #1, #4, #7, #10, ... should have specific css
Children #2, #3, #5, #6, ... should have some other specific css

Had this (:nth-child(3n-2)) for the first, but can't come up with something for the second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `:not(:nth-child(3n-2))` for the second

Comment: lol, that's completely correct. Can't imagine why I couldn't come up with something so clear as this. Nevertheless thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Are children #2, #3, #5, #6, ... just anything other than children #1, #4, #7, #10, ...?

If so, you can either just create a rule for all children in general, then override the styles for children #1, #4, #7, #10, ... like this:

```
.child {
    /* All children */
}

.child:nth-child(3n-2) {
    /* Override for #1, #4, #7, #10, ... */
}
```

Or if you need to specifically apply styles to those children without overriding, you can negate the same `:nth-child()` with `:not()` in a separate rule:

```
.child:nth-child(3n-2) {
    /* #1, #4, #7, #10, ... */
}

.child:not(:nth-child(3n-2)) {
    /* #2, #3, #5, #6, ... */
}
```